# Bad Request: Keyspace ks does not exist. text could not be lexed at line 1, char 13

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I am trying to use COPY  FROM Command in Cassandra using CQL3. Here is What i am trying to do.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE ks WITH strategy_class = 'SimpleStrategy'AND strategy_options:replication_factor = 1;
```

use ks;

```
CREATE TABLE scores1 (id bigint primary key, c_company text, d_company text, date bigint, amount bigint);
```

Uptill this it is working fine.

and even if i am trying to insert it using insert into Command it is working good.
but when i am trying this:

**COPY scores1 (id, company, Ncompany, date, amount) FROM '/home/user/deepak/dd.txt';**

i am getting error:

**Bad Request: Keyspace A_C does not exist**

**text could not be lexed at line 1, char 13**

And again if i am trying with

**COPY scores1 FROM '/home/user/deepak/dd.txt';**

it the error is:
**Column family 'scores1' not found**

Please do help.. any help is appriciated :)

Comment: Can you post the full stack of the error and show us a sample of what is in the dd.txt file? It sounds like you just haven't named your KS / CF for import correctly.

Comment: Your key-space creation statement is CQL2.

`CREATE KEYSPACE ks WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };` is CQL3 . What version of Cassandra are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the column names in your `COPY` statement are not mathing the ones in your `CREATE TABLE` statement. And you might want to prefix the table name in your `COPY` satement with the keyspace name (`keyspace_name.table_name`). Try this:

```
COPY ks.scores1 (id, c_company, d_company, date, amount) FROM '/home/user/deepak/dd.txt';
```

If that's not working, please show us a few lines from your `dd.txt` file.